# Why does my program keep going to the player() method after p1Game() is finished?

Tags: java

Is there any way I'm able to format my code better too? I'm pretty new to programming and want to learn the best optimal way for this program to work. For example: If the word isn't contained in my Words.java then tell the user that the word they're trying to enter doesn't exist.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordleApplication
{
    static String word = Words.words[(int)(Math.random() * Words.words.length)];
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String guess = "";
    static int g = 6;
    static String p1Name = "";
    static String p2Name = "";
    static int p1Score = 0;
    static int p2Score = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rules.rules();
        
        // System.out.println("Please enter your name Player 1");
        // Player p1 = new Player(s.nextLine(), 0);
        // System.out.println(p1.getName());
    }
    
    public static void player(){
        System.out.println("Player 1 Enter your name: ");
        Player p1 = new Player(s.nextLine(), p1Score);
        p1Name = p1.getName();
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Player 2 Enter your name: ");
        Player p2 = new Player(s.nextLine(), p2Score);
        p2Name = p2.getName();
        
        p1Game();
        p2Game();
    }
    
    
    public static void p1Game() {
        System.out.println("Alright " + p1Name + " you're up!");
        while (!guess.equals(word) && g > 0) {
            System.out.println("\nGuesses Left: " + g);
            guess = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (guess.length() != 5) {
                System.out.println("Must be 5 characters");
                continue;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                boolean didBreak = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
                    if (guess.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i)) {
                        System.out.print("Y");
                        didBreak = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (guess.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j)) {
                        System.out.print("C");
                        didBreak = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!didBreak) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + word); //test
            g--;
            if(guess.equals(word)){
                p1Score += 10;
                System.out.println("Nicely done! You have " + p1Score + " points!");
                p2Game();
            }
            if(g == 0){
                System.out.println("\nThe word was: " + word);
                p2Game();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void p2Game() {
        System.out.println("Alright " + p2Name + " you're up!");
        while (!guess.equals(word) && g > 0) {
            System.out.println("\nGuesses Left: " + g);
            guess = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (guess.length() != 5) {
                System.out.println("Must be 5 characters");
                continue;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                boolean didBreak = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
                    if (guess.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i)) {
                        System.out.print("Y");
                        didBreak = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (guess.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j)) {
                        System.out.print("C");
                        didBreak = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!didBreak) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + word); //test
            g--;
            if(guess.equals(word)){
                System.out.println("Nicely done!");
                p2Score += 10;
            }
            if(g == 0){
                System.out.println("\nThe word was: " + word);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void results(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    
}
```

Just the rules to describe what to the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rules {
    public static void rules() {
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enterkey;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Wordle!");
        System.out.println("Each player will be given 6 tries to guess a 5 letter word.");
        System.out.println("If you can't guess the word in 6 tries. GAME OVER :(");
        System.out.println("Do you have what it takes to guess the word?");
        System.out.println("Go ahead and press y when you're ready!");
        
        while(true){
            enterkey = s.nextLine();
            if(!enterkey.equals("y")){
                System.out.println("Please press y to continue...");
                continue;
            }
            if(enterkey.equals("y")){
                WordleApplication.player();
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
public class Player {
    
    protected String name;
    protected int score;
    
    public Player(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = 10;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + score;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class Words {
    public static String[] words = {
        "abuse",
        "adult",
        "agent",
        "anger",
        "apple",
        "award",
        "basis",
        "beach",
        "birth",
        "block",
        "blood",
        "board",
        "brain",
        "bread",
        "break",
        "brown",
        "buyer",
        "cause",
        "chain",
        "chair",
        "chest",
        "chief",
        "child",
        "china",
        "claim",
        "class",
        "clock",
        "coach",
        "coast",
        "court",
        "cover",
        "cream",
        "crime",
        "cross",
        "crowd",
        "crown",
        "cycle",
        "dance",
        "death",
        "depth",
        "doubt",
        "draft",
        "drama",
        "dream",
        "dress",
        "drink",
        "drive",
        "earth",
        "enemy",
        "entry",
        "error",
        "event",
        "faith",
        "fault",
        "field",
        "fight",
        "final",
        "floor",
        "focus",
        "force",
        "frame",
        "frank",
        "front",
        "fruit",
        "glass",
        "grant",
        "grass",
        "green",
        "group",
        "guide",
        "heart",
        "henry",
        "horse",
        "hotel",
        "house",
        "image",
        "index",
        "input",
        "issue",
        "japan",
        "jones",
        "judge",
        "knife",
        "laura",
        "layer",
        "level",
        "lewis",
        "light",
        "limit",
        "lunch",
        "major",
        "march",
        "match",
        "metal",
        "model",
        "money",
        "month",
        "motor",
        "mouth",
        "music",
        "night",
        "noise",
        "north",
        "novel",
        "nurse",
        "offer",
        "order",
        "other",
        "owner",
        "panel",
        "paper",
        "party",
        "peace",
        "peter",
        "phase",
        "phone",
        "piece",
        "pilot",
        "pitch",
        "place",
        "plane",
        "plant",
        "plate",
        "point",
        "pound",
        "power",
        "press",
        "price",
        "pride",
        "prize",
        "proof",
        "queen",
        "radio",
        "range",
        "ratio",
        "reply",
        "right",
        "river",
        "round",
        "route",
        "rugby",
        "scale",
        "scene",
        "scope",
        "score",
        "sense",
        "shape",
        "share",
        "sheep",
        "sheet",
        "shift",
        "shirt",
        "shock",
        "sight",
        "simon",
        "skill",
        "sleep",
        "smile",
        "smith",
        "smoke",
        "sound",
        "south",
        "space",
        "speed",
        "spite",
        "sport",
        "squad",
        "staff",
        "stage",
        "start",
        "state",
        "steam",
        "steel",
        "stock",
        "stone",
        "store",
        "study",
        "stuff",
        "style",
        "sugar",
        "table",
        "taste",
        "terry",
        "theme",
        "thing",
        "title",
        "total",
        "touch",
        "tower",
        "track",
        "trade",
        "train",
        "trend",
        "trial",
        "trust",
        "truth",
        "uncle",
        "union",
        "unity",
        "value",
        "video",
        "visit",
        "voice",
        "waste",
        "watch",
        "water",
        "while",
        "white",
        "whole",
        "woman",
        "world",
        "youth",
        "alcon",
        "aught",
        "hella",
        "one’s",
        "ought",
        "thame",
        "there",
        "thine",
        "thine",
        "where",
        "which",
        "whose",
        "whoso",
        "yours",
        "yours",
        "admit",
        "adopt",
        "agree",
        "allow",
        "alter",
        "apply",
        "argue",
        "arise",
        "avoid",
        "begin",
        "blame",
        "break",
        "bring",
        "build",
        "burst",
        "carry",
        "catch",
        "cause",
        "check",
        "claim",
        "clean",
        "clear",
        "climb",
        "close",
        "count",
        "cover",
        "cross",
        "dance",
        "doubt",
        "drink",
        "drive",
        "enjoy",
        "enter",
        "exist",
        "fight",
        "focus",
        "force",
        "guess",
        "imply",
        "issue",
        "judge",
        "laugh",
        "learn",
        "leave",
        "let’s",
        "limit",
        "marry",
        "match",
        "occur",
        "offer",
        "order",
        "phone",
        "place",
        "point",
        "press",
        "prove",
        "raise",
        "reach",
        "refer",
        "relax",
        "serve",
        "shall",
        "share",
        "shift",
        "shoot",
        "sleep",
        "solve",
        "sound",
        "speak",
        "spend",
        "split",
        "stand",
        "start",
        "state",
        "stick",
        "study",
        "teach",
        "thank",
        "think",
        "throw",
        "touch",
        "train",
        "treat",
        "trust",
        "visit",
        "voice",
        "waste",
        "watch",
        "worry",
        "would",
        "write",
        "above",
        "acute",
        "alive",
        "alone",
        "angry",
        "aware",
        "awful",
        "basic",
        "black",
        "blind",
        "brave",
        "brief",
        "broad",
        "brown",
        "cheap",
        "chief",
        "civil",
        "clean",
        "clear",
        "close",
        "crazy",
        "daily",
        "dirty",
        "early",
        "empty",
        "equal",
        "exact",
        "extra",
        "faint",
        "false",
        "fifth",
        "final",
        "first",
        "fresh",
        "front",
        "funny",
        "giant",
        "grand",
        "great",
        "green",
        "gross",
        "happy",
        "harsh",
        "heavy",
        "human",
        "ideal",
        "inner",
        "joint",
        "large",
        "legal",
        "level",
        "light",
        "local",
        "loose",
        "lucky",
        "magic",
        "major",
        "minor",
        "moral",
        "naked",
        "nasty",
        "naval",
        "other",
        "outer",
        "plain",
        "prime",
        "prior",
        "proud",
        "quick",
        "quiet",
        "rapid",
        "ready",
        "right",
        "roman",
        "rough",
        "round",
        "royal",
        "rural",
        "sharp",
        "sheer",
        "short",
        "silly",
        "sixth",
        "small",
        "smart",
        "solid",
        "sorry",
        "spare",
        "steep",
        "still",
        "super",
        "sweet",
        "thick",
        "third",
        "tight",
        "total",
        "tough",
        "upper",
        "upset",
        "urban",
        "usual",
        "vague",
        "valid",
        "vital",
        "white",
        "whole",
        "wrong",
        "young",
        "afore",
        "after",
        "bothe",
        "other",
        "since",
        "slash",
        "until",
        "where",
        "while",
        "aback",
        "abaft",
        "aboon",
        "about",
        "above",
        "accel",
        "adown",
        "afoot",
        "afore",
        "afoul",
        "after",
        "again",
        "agape",
        "agogo",
        "agone",
        "ahead",
        "ahull",
        "alife",
        "alike",
        "aline",
        "aloft",
        "alone",
        "along",
        "aloof",
        "aloud",
        "amiss",
        "amply",
        "amuck",
        "apace",
        "apart",
        "aptly",
        "arear",
        "aside",
        "askew",
        "awful",
        "badly",
        "bally",
        "below",
        "canny",
        "cheap",
        "clean",
        "clear",
        "coyly",
        "daily",
        "dimly",
        "dirty",
        "ditto",
        "drily",
        "dryly",
        "dully",
        "early",
        "extra",
        "false",
        "fatly",
        "feyly",
        "first",
        "fitly",
        "forte",
        "forth",
        "fresh",
        "fully",
        "funny",
        "gaily",
        "gayly",
        "godly",
        "great",
        "haply",
        "heavy",
        "hella",
        "hence",
        "hotly",
        "icily",
        "infra",
        "intl.",
        "jildi",
        "jolly",
        "laxly",
        "lento",
        "light",
        "lowly",
        "madly",
        "maybe",
        "never",
        "newly",
        "nobly",
        "oddly",
        "often",
        "other",
        "ought",
        "party",
        "piano",
        "plain",
        "plonk",
        "plumb",
        "prior",
        "queer",
        "quick",
        "quite",
        "ramen",
        "rapid",
        "redly",
        "right",
        "rough",
        "round",
        "sadly",
        "secus",
        "selly",
        "sharp",
        "sheer",
        "shily",
        "short",
        "shyly",
        "silly",
        "since",
        "sleek",
        "slyly",
        "small",
        "so-so",
        "sound",
        "spang",
        "srsly",
        "stark",
        "still",
        "stone",
        "stour",
        "super",
        "tally",
        "tanto",
        "there",
        "thick",
        "tight",
        "today",
        "tomoz",
        "truly",
        "twice",
        "under",
        "utter",
        "verry",
        "wanly",
        "wetly",
        "where",
        "wrong",
        "wryly",
        "abaft",
        "aboon",
        "about",
        "above",
        "adown",
        "afore",
        "after",
        "along",
        "aloof",
        "among",
        "below",
        "circa",
        "cross",
        "furth",
        "minus",
        "neath",
        "round",
        "since",
        "spite",
        "under",
        "until",
        "aargh",
        "adieu",
        "adios",
        "alack",
        "aloha",
        "avast",
        "bakaw",
        "basta",
        "begad",
        "bless",
        "blige",
        "brava",
        "bravo",
        "bring",
        "chook",
        "damme",
        "dildo",
        "ditto",
        "frick",
        "fudge",
        "golly",
        "gratz",
        "hallo",
        "hasta",
        "havoc",
        "hella",
        "hello",
        "howay",
        "howdy",
        "hullo",
        "huzza",
        "jesus",
        "kapow",
        "loose",
        "lordy",
        "marry",
        "mercy",
        "night",
        "plonk",
        "psych",
        "quite",
        "salve",
        "skoal",
        "sniff",
        "sooey",
        "there",
        "thiam",
        "thwap",
        "tough",
        "twirp",
        "viola",
        "vivat",
        "wacko",
        "wahey",
        "whist",
        "wilma",
        "wirra",
        "woops",
        "wowie",
        "yecch",
        "yeeha",
        "yeesh",
        "yowch",
        "zowie"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it goes to `p2Game` because you tell it to several times.

In `player()` you call `p1Game` then you call `p2Game` that's cool, that'd work.  When `p1Game` finishes, it goes back to `player`, and the next line is `p2Game` which is probably what you want.

BUT, you call `p2Game` a number of times within `p1Game` which is probably what's causing the problem.  The two times in `p1Game` that you call `p2Game` are probably unnecessary.

What happens right now, is player 1 guesses the correct word.  You say "Nicely done!" then call `p2Game`. Player 2 has a go, when that finishes, control goes back into `p1Game` carries on, it rolls out of `p1Game` eventually finishes, goes back to `player` and `p2Game` gets another call.

So, ditch those calls to `p2Game` inside the `p1Game` method.

In terms of organising your code better.  Yes, there are a couple of things:

- avoid repeating code.  `p1Game` and `p2Game` look almost identical. If you find yourself writing code like that, you should think about a different way to go.  There's a programming principle called "DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself"
- avoid `static` when you're using an object oriented language like Java.  Might as well be writing BASIC in 1986.

Normally the `main` method is the only `static` method.

```
public static void main() 
{
   WordleApplication wa = new WordleApplication();
   wa.player();
}
```

You'd take `static` off your `player` method.

Change your `p1Game` method so it accepts a `Player` object as a parameter:

```
public static void OneGame(Player p) {
    System.out.println("Alright " + p.getName() + " you're up!");
    while (!guess.equals(word) && g > 0) {
        System.out.println("\nGuesses Left: " + g);
...
```

See how it uses the parameter for the name in the "you're up" line? extend that through out the method.

So then, at the bottom of the `player` method,
instead of

```
p1Game()
p2Game()
```

you can instead do

```
OneGame (p1);
OneGame (p2);
```

And that means you can delete `p2Game` entirely. And that's good because less code is better code.

The static variables are also bad form.  They're basically "Global Variables" in your app, and it's really hard to keep track of global variables once your app gets a lot bigger.   It's better to minimise who can modify the variable.  One example is `g`.  This is only need inside the game method.  So if you move it to the start of the `OneGame` method and set it to 6, you'll be good.  As it is, it *looks* like both players get 6 guesses between them.  If player 1 takes 5 guesses, Player 2 is only going to get 1 guess.

So

- move the variables that *could* be inside the 'game' method in there.  That's `guess` and `g` and probably `word` unless you *do* want both players guessing the same word?
- move the variables that belong to the player into the player object.  So instead of the `p1Name` variable refer to `getName()` method of the `p` parameter.  Instead of `p1Score` use `setScore` and `getScore`

It looks like you've put a chunk of effort into this.  I think with a bit more it'll all just fall into place.

Good luck.